# Trigger with condition on insert not inserting row

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm working with mysql and I'm need to trigger on insert from a table when there's a condition.

The information that is going to be inserted on the Table1 are user metadata, when there's a new user registration it's inserted 8 new rows. I want the trigger to be fired when the metadata_key is *'first name'*

My problem here is if a put this **condition inside the trigger**, this **row is never inserted**, so the **information is missing and the trigger is never fired**.

These are my tables:

```
+---------------------Table1---------------+ Table which fires the trigger AFTER INSERT 
+ user_id | meta_key     | meta_value      +
+ -----------------------------------------+
+      1  | first_name   | luke            +
+      1  | second_name  | skywalker       +
+------------------------------------------+

' 
+-----------------Table2------------------+ Where I need to INSERT
+ post_author | post_content | post_title +
+ ----------------------------------------+
+        0    | hub         | luke        +
+-----------------------------------------+
```

**Code**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `post` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `anagomez`@`localhost` TRIGGER `post` AFTER INSERT ON  `table1` 

FOR EACH ROW INSERT 

if(new.meta_key='first_name') then

insert into table2(post_author,post_content,post_title) values ('0','hub',new.meta_value);

end if
```

Any advice?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(new.metadata_key='first_name') then` rather than `new.meta_key`

Comment: Thanks, actually is meta_key and meta_value, I wrote them wrong in the example but it's ok in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is almost correct but there is a small issue and it should look like

```
delimiter //

CREATE DEFINER =  `anagomez`@`localhost` TRIGGER `post` AFTER INSERT ON  `table1` 

FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN

   if(new.meta_key='first_name') then

     insert into table2(post_author,post_content,post_title) values ('0','hub',new.meta_value);

   end if;
end; //
delimiter ;
```

I have added the delimiter and the issue was you were missing the `BEGIN` and instead you added `INSERT`

Comment: The thing is I'm working in phpMyAdmin, so it has an online editor for triggers, procedures... I think I don't have to delimiter anything, just write the code which is supposed to be inside the delimiter, am I wrong?

Comment: Well I am not sure about the PHPAmyadmin, you can try without the delimiter, its needed when you run the trigger on mysql terminal. But yes if you add BEGIN and END to the trigger it should work.

Comment: Well, Table2 is firing another trigger to update Table1, so we have two triggers, the 1st from Table1 AFTER INSERT and the 2nd from Table2 AFTER UPDATE. So it looks like the conflict is because Table1 is being modified while Table2 is trying to change something, it might be locked. How can I fix this so I can make it work?

Comment: hmm so when the trigger is fired on table2 after update its inserting a new record on table1 ? or its update ? if update then it should be fine but if insert with first_name as meta_key then it will be a dead lock kind of situation.